# Adding multiple elements issue using ReactDOM.render in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I am new to react js and i am trying to add HTML elements multiple times using  `ReactDOM.render` but when I add elements to the dom multiple times the element is replaced each time not added one by one as a new element

this is my code:

```
  const questionPreview = document.getElementById('question-preview');

  let input = React.createElement("input",{className:"questionTextInput",name:"textInputQuestion[]"},null);
  ReactDOM.render(input,questionPreview);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ReactDOM.createPortal` inside of `ReactDOM.render` like this

```
ReactDOM.render(ReactDOM.createPortal(questionForm,questionPreview), document.createElement('div'));
```